# Is there a way to generate cryptographically strong random numbers in Go similar to Python's `secrets` module?

Tags: go, random

Using python you could use the `secrets` module like this.

```py
    import secrets
    print(secrets.token_hex(16))

    >>> a67c39a93429f53e5c2a711b0c8455b6
```

Is there a similar way to do this using Go?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [crypto/rand](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) package, something like this:

```
b := make([]byte, length)
_, err := rand.Read(b)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error reading random token:", err)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The question asks 'Is there a similar way to do this using Go?'

Comment: I apologize again :)

Comment: No problem, easily done.